# IIS redirect without a separate site

Tags: iis, redirect

Given multiple domain bindings, how do I configure my IIS site to redirect all requests to a primary domain without creating a second site to handle only the redirect?

Answer (score 0):

## This is now a built-in IIS 7 feature:

1. Go to URL Rewrite.
2. Click Add Rule.
3. Select *Canonical Domain Name* under *Search Engine Optimization*.
4. Enter canonical domain and save.

Comment: If you figured it out yourself, accept your own answer, so that it doesn't figure as unanswered

Comment: You can only accept your own answer in ~24 hours.